# Object Required on a Variant

Tags: vba, excel

I have the error 424 'object required' on the line `tableauScores(i - 1, j).Value = wsScores.Cells(2 + i * 3, j + 1).Value` in the following sub.

There is only this sub, nothing else. I am in Base 0.

```
    Dim wsScores As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim tableauScores As Variant

    Set wsScores = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scores")        
    j = 0

    ReDim tableauScores(1, 2)

    If wsScores.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Thomas" Then        
        For i = 1 To 2
            For j = 1 To 3
                tableauScores(i - 1, j).Value = wsScores.Cells(2 + i * 3, j + 1).Value
            Next j
        Next i            
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't get why, I always use variant like this.

Comment: You could use `ReDim tableauScores(1 To 2, 1 To 3)` to make your calculation easier

Comment: [Variant data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448.aspx) doen't have property `Value` on its own. To assign value to `Variant` you simply assign it to the variable itself.

Comment: @dee The main point is not that `Variant` doesn't have a `Value` property. The following code will work: `Dim v As Variant: Set v = ActiveWorksheet.Cells(1,1): Debug.Print v.Value`; even though the variable `v` is of type `Variant`, the object to which it refers does have a `Value` property, and VBA will resolve the property at runtime.

Comment: @ShaiRado what does it change to put "a to b" in redim ? Thanks

Comment: @TmSmth that you array count start from 1 to 2, and not 0 to 1, so your indexing inside the array will be easier to manipulate with the cells (rows, Columns)

Comment: @ShaiRado oh ok but if i was using base 1, would it be a difference betweem redim array(2,3) and redim array(1 to 2, 2 to 3) ?

Comment: @TmSmth  no, it would be the same

Comment: @ShaiRado Ok thanks for your explanation

Comment: @ZevSpitz yes but it is important to distinguish between setting value of `Variant` variable and setting value of object which if referenced by this variable. The first can't be done with `Value` property because `Variant` doesn't have one. That was what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tableuScores` is defined as an array of `Variant` — `Variant()` — and until a given array element is initialized, it will have a value of `Empty`. It's impossible to read the `Value` property of `Empty`.

Consider doing this without `Value`:

```
tableauScores(i - 1, j) = wsScores.Cells(2 + i * 3, j + 1).Value
```

Comment: Yes, just modify your answer, It's `Empty' before initialized

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks; fixed.